# Error in result by driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'f nsa _uQb')]"));

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/webhp?
                     hl=en#hl=en&tbm=nws&q=site+:+www.google.com");
java.util.List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(
                     By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'f nsa _uQb')]"));

 System.out.println(dates.size());
```

Trying above code... I am getting output `zero`, rather than what it should be, `10`.

Please suggest if i am doing something wrong...

Comment: please post the html source code for the same

Comment: Please visit to the link mentioned in above code driver.get("..........");

Comment: are you trying to extract search results

Comment: Yes Raj i am trying to fetch the Date mentioned in every result.. That date is published date of story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please find the answer

```
public class FetchDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver .get("https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&tbm=nws&q=site+:+www.google.com");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".f.nsa._uQb"));
        // for finding size 
        System.out.println(dates.size());

        // for printing every date 

        for(WebElement Dates : dates){
            System.out.println("date for the search is : " + Dates.getText());
        }
```

UPDATE :

```
// for printing the way you want do it like below 
List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".f.nsa._uQb"));
     for (int j = 0; j < dates.size(); j++) {
                String date = dates.get(j).getText(); 
                System.out.println(date);
            }
            }
    }
```

and the output is :

```
10
date for the search is : 29-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 03-May-2016
date for the search is : 29-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 20-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 16-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 30-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 25-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 25-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 21-Apr-2016
date for the search is : 07-Apr-2016
```

Comment: Yes... and i wanted to fecth the Published date of every result

Comment: Hi Raj... For printing i am using below code and its showing error. for (int j = 0; j < dates.size(); j++) 
  {
   String date = dates.get(j).findElement(By.cssSelector(".f.nsa._uQb")).getText();
   System.out.println(dates);}

Comment: Also plz not that you have already defined dates before the for loop like   List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".f.nsa._uQb")); so no need to define it further

Comment: Hi Raj .... i am getting error in line String date = dates.get(j).findElement(By.cssSelector(".f.nsa._uQb")).getText(); and the error message is Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".f.nsa._uQb"}

Comment: I have update my comment and answer plz do it like that ,you willl not face any error

Answer (score 0):

Your way of construction xpath is wrong try this one,

**//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' f nsa _uQb ')]**

> java.util.List dates = driver.findElements(
>                        By.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' f nsa _uQb ')]"));

**Note the spaces**

Comment: This is also return output zero.

Comment: did u provide some wait?

Answer (score 0):

The dates are in `<span>` tag, not `<div>`. Try

```
List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'f nsa _uQb')]"));
```

You can also find the dates by the `nsa` or `_uQb` classes

```
List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.className("nsa"));

List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.className("_uQb"));
```